# Format independent serialization in python

Tags: python, serialization

I was recently looking for methods to serialize a python class and only found topics that cover format specific libraries like `pickle` and `json`. Is there a way to make a python class serializable without committing to the concrete format?

To be more specific: When programming in C++ I often use the boost serialization library. There, you can add serialization of a class `Foo` by implementing a `serialize` method:

```
struct Foo
{
    int some_number;
    std::string some_string;
}

template <typename Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, Foo& foo, unsigned int const version)
{
    ar & foo.some_number;
    ar & foo.some_string;
}
```

The concrete output format is determined by the `Archive` type. For example, you can call the method with an xml archive, a binary archive, or a json archive, and retrieve output in the respective format. This means that you only have to implement a single method where you list the members and are now able to serialize the class in all formats.

I tried to do something similar in python and ended up with a lot of if-else statements. In python you cannot overload a method for different types so I had to implement a multiplexer that calls the class-specific serialization methods:

```
def serialize(archive, value, version):
    if isinstance(value, Foo):
        serialize_foo(archive, value, version)
    elif isinstance(value, Bar):
        serialize_bar(archive, value, version)
    ...
```

Is there a better way to add format-independent serialization to a class? An ideal solution should satisfy the following:

- Decentral: When adding serialization to a class only the file which contains the class should be changed. I dont want to end up with a central file with giant if-elif-else statements.
- Allow nested classes: If class `Foo` has a member of type `Bar` and `Bar` is serializable, then I can reuse that when serializing `Foo` without reimplementing the whole serialization of `Bar`.
- (Optional) Same method for reading / writing. Boost serialization makes this possible by distinguishing between input and output archives.
- (Optional) Non intrusive: You can add serialization to a class without touching the class.

Comment: Not sure if you can use a third party package, but have a look at [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You can also dig into its source code to get some ideas.

Comment: Third party libraries are okay. The marshmallow library looks promising, I will check it out :)

Comment: The only thing I am missing in marshmallow is a version number in the files. Do you know similar library with the option of passing a version to the serializers?

Comment: I confirm i used to use marshmallow too, even though i had issues  months ago around  different semantic between loading and dumping but looks like they fixed it.